# Webpack vendor dll Reference Error

Tags: javascript, webpack

Building webpack vendor dll and getting

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: vendors_9a2b8ee29a9e8dcdc486b49a360b9763 is not defined
```

The compiled code is coming out as

```
module.exports = vendors_9a2b8ee29a9e8dcdc486b49a360b9763;

//////////////////
// WEBPACK FOOTER
// external "vendors_9a2b8ee29a9e8dcdc486b49a360b9763"
// module id = 2
// module chunks = 0
```

it is missing the declaration and locating of something like

```
var angular = __webpack_require__(2)

module.exports = (__webpack_require__(3))(1)
```

I have no idea why this is and I've tried absolutely everything. Here is the plugins for my webpack config:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
        context: '.',
        manifest: require('./src/tmp/vendors-manifest.json')
    }),
],
```

and here is my dll config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var packageJSON = require('./package.json');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendors: Object.keys(packageJSON.devDependencies),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'src/tmp'),
        filename: 'vendors.bundle.js',
        library: 'vendors_[hash]'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: 'src/tmp/[name]-manifest.json',
            name: 'vendors_[hash]'
        }),
    ]
};
```

index.html imports:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/src/tmp/vendors.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/js/app.js"></script>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Are you including the `vendors.bundle.js` before your app bundle?

Comment: The vendor bundle is in `/src/tmp/vendors.bundle.js` according to your config, not `/tmp/vendors.bundle.js`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when I was typing it out here it is namespaced under src in my app and I still get the problem.

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you resolve it ?

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem.
it solved by changing the context.

```
plugins: [
new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'src/tmp'),
    manifest: require('./src/tmp/vendors-manifest.json')
})]
```

Comment: same. i spent hours debugging this. thanks for the heads up

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem and this worked for me.

Comment: In addition to these answers, make sure you are running the same version of node in processes that consume these files. Different node versions can cause a different hash if you are using hashed file names, and the mismatch causes this error.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. I had to add the "library" option to the output section with the same name.

```
   // Location of webpack output
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dll'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        library: '[name]'
    },

    plugins: [            
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: require(path.join(__dirname, 'dll/[name]-manifest.json')),
            name: '[name]',
        })
    ]
```

Answer (score -3):

Modify you dll config file, and set your code to

```
new webpack.DllPlugin({
    path: 'path.join(__dirname, 'src/tmp/manifest.json')',
    name: 'vendors_[hash]'
}),
```

and in you config file and modify you DllReferencePlugin to this

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
        context: __dirname,
        manifest: require(path.join(__dirname, 'src/tmp/manifest.json')),
        name: 'vendors_9a2b8ee29a9e8dcdc486b49a360b9763'
    }),
],
```